# Custom product attribute not showing in admin catalog section magento 2.1

Tags: magento, attributes

I have added custom product attribute in Magento 2.1 and that product is showing in attribute section but couldn't be shown in magento catalog section where we have created products

Below are the code which I am using to create attribute.

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
     */

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'test_author',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Test Author',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

[image]

Comment: In magento 2.1, you need to add ui_component to show custom attribute in catalog form section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code -

```
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
/**
* Add attributes to the eav/attribute
*/
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
'test_author',
[
'group' => 'General',
'type' => 'int',
'backend' => '',
'frontend' => '',
'label' => 'Test Author',
'input' => 'textarea',
'class' => '',
'source' => '',
'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'visible' => true,
'required' => false,
'user_defined' => true,
'default' => '',
'searchable' => false,
'filterable' => false,
'comparable' => false,
'visible_on_front' => false,
'used_in_product_listing' => true,
'unique' => false,
'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
]
);
```